# Ember.js blog app architecture

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ember.js

I decided to create simple blog app by using `Ember.js` which should has the following interface

[image: Blog mockup]

For this purpose I created `blog` route which contain the following code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('currentPost', 0);
    controller.set('model', model.objectAt(controller.get('currentPost')));
  },

  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('blog-post');
  },

  actions: {
    nextPost: function () {
      var controller = this.controller;
      controller.incrementProperty('currentPost');
      this.store.find('blog-post').then(function (value) {
        controller.set('model', value.objectAt(controller.get('currentPost')));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In `blog.hbs` I have `blog-post` component. This component receive data from model, which is filtered inside `setupController` method, in order to load only one post, but not the whole array of posts. But when user clicks `Next` button, I need update data in component, and it's done in `nextPost` method. It works good, but it's look weird and ugly, because we access to store and retrieve the model data, however it has already done in `model` hook.

```
nextPost: function () {
          var controller = this.controller;
          controller.incrementProperty('currentPost');
          this.store.find('blog-post').then(function (value) {
            controller.set('model', value.objectAt(controller.get('currentPost')));
          });
        }
```

What app design changes I need to do or to refactor the code, in order to make it clear and concise?